# Com rodar o Docker passando uma URL diferente

Tags: mongodb, docker

Tenho uma aplicação rodando back end com NestJS, TypeORM e MongoDB e meu front end rodando React.

Criei um container Docker para rodar todas as aplicações porem estou com um problema.

Para rodar o meu back end local a url de conexão é mongodb://localhost:27017/db e para o docker preciso utilizar mongodb://mongo:27017/db

Existe alguma forma de eu configurar meu docker-composer.yml para fazer essa alteração?

Abaixo meu docker compose.

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  client:
    build:
      context: ./web
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    working_dir: /web/src/app
    volumes:
      - ./web:/web/src/app
    entrypoint: ["npm", "start"]
    links:
      - api
    networks:
      - webappnetwork
  api:
    build:
      context: ./backend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "3333:3333"
    volumes:
      - ./backend:/backend
      - /backend/node_modules
    depends_on:
      - mongodb
    networks:
      - webappnetwork
  mongodb:
    image: mongo
    restart: always
    container_name: mongodb
    volumes:
      - ./data:/data/db
    ports:
      - 27018:27017
    command: mongod --noauth
    networks:
      - webappnetwork
networks:
  webappnetwork:
    driver: bridge
```

Abaixo meu arquivo de conexão bd.

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { CardsModule } from './cards/cards.module';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';

@Module({
  imports: [
    CardsModule,
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
      type: 'mongodb',
      url: 'mongodb://localhost:27017/db',
      entities: [__dirname + '/**/*.entity{.ts,.js}'],
      synchronize: true,
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
    }),
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Obrigado a todos!

Answer (score 0):

O ideal é que você utilize variáveis de ambiente para configurar sua aplicação, como configuração de banco de dados por exemplo.

Um jeito simples seria trocar usa configuração do DB para:

```
...
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
      type: 'mongodb',
      url: `mongodb://${process.env.DB_HOST}:${process.env.DB_PORT}/db`,
      entities: [__dirname + '/**/*.entity{.ts,.js}'],
      synchronize: true,
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
    }),
...
```

Assim em desenvolvimento você usa as variáveis de ambiente com sua configuração de dev:

```
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT= 27017
```

E quando fazendo deploy no seu docker-compose você passa novas variáveis de ambiente:

```yml
...
  api:
    build:
      context: ./backend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "3333:3333"
    volumes:
      - ./backend:/backend
      - /backend/node_modules
    depends_on:
      - mongodb
    networks:
      - webappnetwork
    environment:
      DB_HOST: mongodb
      DB_PORT: 27017
...
```

Esta é a maneira correta de lidar com configuração de aplicações, agora você só precisa ver como o seu framework te ajuda nessa questão de configuração com variáveis de ambiente.

Fazendo um google rápido vi que o NestJS possuí uma sessão na documentação sobre o assunto: https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/configuration#configuration